# "vendor" folder missing after running "Composer Install"

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am currently trying to run on Vagrant/Homestead a Laravel Application that I pulled from Github. I connected it to the database, and run Composer Install, Composer Update inside the folder. When I try to access to it on the Browser I get the following error:

**Warning: require(/home/vagrant/.../public/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/..../public/autoload.php on line 2**

I navigated to the vendor folder and noticed that it was not created. Any ideas how to fix it?

The application runs in Laravel 4, and I got the following output from the terminal when I run Composer Install:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package herrera-io/json is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use kherge/json instead.
Package kherge/version is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package herrera-io/phar-update is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package mjolnic/bootstrap-colorpicker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker instead.
```

Generating autoload files

> php artisan clear-compiled
>   php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried composer install --no-scripts

Comment: I just did, and got the same error while trying to access to the application on the browser.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the command line while running `composer install`?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The output of the terminal when I run composer install is on the question. This is an old Application running on Laravel 4 that I need to test locally using Homestead. Maybe outdated packages are causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer needs to be run from the root of your application, i.e. not from the `public` folder as your error seems to indicate.

You can first try running:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

This command should list the packages that are being downloaded and installed. If the above works, you can then run:

```
php artisan optimize
```

This will create the autoload.php file that Laravel will use.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. composer install --no-scripts works, but when the "vendor" folder is still not created and when running "php artisan optimize" I get the same "vendor/autoload.php not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced that, i solved the problem by creating a vendor/bin folder inside the Composer directory.

```
$PATH/users/*-system_name-*/AppData/Roaming/Composer
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem, some answer are valid but didnt help then i tried a command =  composer  dump-autoload. Then it works fine. HOPE this helps you the best.