# How to fix error when creating an controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am using below command to create controller.

```
$ php artisan make:controller PagesController
```

After executing command getting below error.

> PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevApp\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear` and then `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`. Also what version of laravel are you running?

Comment: try `composer install`, seems you are missing vendor folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["vendor" folder missing after running "Composer Install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186191/vendor-folder-missing-after-running-composer-install)

Answer (score 1):

Just run this inside the directory where you installed your project:

```
composer install
```

after

```
php artisan make:controller PagesController
```

Answer (score 0):

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

run this command after that add a env file to your folder