Vendor folder not found on Laravel 11
After run composer create-project laravel/laravel:^11.0 project-name then going to my project folder cd project-name after that i should run php artisan serve but i got an error at this step that seems vendor folder not found in my project
Please note: If i using laravel 8 it's work fine but i need to use laravel 11
Help me, Thank!
My php version is 8.2.10
Try to using laravel 11 but can't, On the other hand laravel 8 works find.
PLease note that I'am try to run composer install and composer update and remove composer cache
Full error message: "PHP Warning:  require(/home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/artisan on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/artisan:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/artisan on line 9"

try running removing composer.lock from your gitignore file and then running those commands again. Laracasts Question

@s4D_t0y Thank but there is no .gitignore file on project folder!

Are you sure? It is a hidden file, so you might not be able to see it. (I do not know what OS you are on, however, so I don't want to jump to conclusions)

@s4D_t0y I forgot to say that but I'am using Linux ubuntu OS

@Sidik Thanks for your effort, But I already have a composer.json file

@AhmedElmoslmany,  try doing composer install in verbose mode; i.e. compoer -vvvv install. Perhaps there is some error that u can't see

Something must have gone wrong with the project setup, or you have changed something after creating it. I just tried a new project and the vendor is there and I can run php artisan serve. You said "i got an error at this step that seems vendor folder not found in my project" - please add the full error message to your question, it might tell us something you are missing

What is the error? Does this address your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186191/vendor-folder-missing-after-running-composer-install

@Tony Add full error message to the question please take a look, Thanks in advance!

If you have a solution for your problem, please post it as an answer, not as an update to your question

The error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/vendor/autoload.php'

says the autoload.php file is missing. This file can be created using the command composer dump-autoload.
If that does not run successfully you might need to run composer install first.
I've tried this on a Laravel 11 project where the vendor folder has been deleted and the project can be served successfully after:
$composer install
...
$composer dump-autoload
...
$php artisan serve

 INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000]. 

If your project does not work after running these commands we'll need more information to help fix it.

After run composer dump-autoload command i face new error and that is the message:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/bootstrap/app.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/artisan(12): require_once()
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/ahmedelmoslmany/Laravel-demo/example-app11/bootstrap/app.php on line 7
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

And this is a completely new project you have created with composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app11, which you have not modified in any way? Did you also run composer install, where there any errors?

Thanks @Tony
When run composer install I paid attention to this warning
"Composer is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have the PHP curl extension enabled."
I gave this error to chatgpt and followed him until I solved it.
I don't know why that's happening but it's working now!
